# The layout on emulator and android phone are not same

Tags: android-emulator, android-layout, absolutelayout

[image: This is picture on android phone]

[image: This is picture on emulator]

They are not same, what should I do ?
Thanks :)

Comment: (Off-topic: There's a typo on your *Cancel* button...)

Comment: @Nanne What is that ?
@stakx Thaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the screen properties (resolution etc) aren't the same, so the layout can have a different effect. Debug your layout on several different screens (you can change them in different VM's).